# How to disable methods invocations logging in slf4j?

Tags: java, slf4j

Please, take a look at this example:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);
      log.info("Hello World");
   }
}
```

The program generates following output:

```
2011-11-01 13:06:05 Test main
INFO: Hello World
```

How to get rid of the first line? How to set Logger not to show methods invocations?

slf4j uses jdk14 in my application. In addition, I have two handlers, so it would be nice if there would be a way to disable methods invocations logging just for one handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two lines are both generated by the call to `log.info`. It seems the logger implementation default format generates line breaks. In no way "method entry" itself produces any output.

To make it clear: If you log twice as in

```
log.info("Hello World1");
log.info("Hello World2");
```

I expect this output:

```
2011-11-01 13:06:05 Test main
INFO: Hello World1
2011-11-01 13:06:05 Test main
INFO: Hello World2
```

Oh, and the general way to setup Java-Util-Logging for your JDK is described here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html

You will have to look out the "Formatters" section and implement your own formatter (AFAIK). Or simply use a usable logging implementation behind slf4j like logback or log4j.

Comment: I implemented my own formatter, thanks for advice. Anyway, do you recommend switching from jdk to logback or log4j?

Comment: @Radek Well what`s the value of a logging implementation with no codebase, no compatibility with other frameworks, containing only two output formatters which on top of it even don't allow the specification of common output formats, providing no interface separation and is moreover extremely ugly to configure and initialize. I think you get the drift.